# Jquery How to change url for every ajax respond

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".blok").newWindow({
 windowTitle:"Example1",
 ajaxURL:"Action.php?task=BlokDuzenleFormGetirBlokId="+$(".blok").attr('id')
});
```

when first clicked on blok class a href, newWindow loads from data by `$(".blok").attr('id').` Then every action sen same url to ajax, with not change. is there a way change url every single respond to call function by unique id parametre or anything like  that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".blok").each(function(){
  $(this).newWindow({
     windowTitle:"Example1",
     ajaxURL:"Action.php?task=BlokDuzenleFormGetirBlokId="+$(this).attr('id')
  });

});
```

Comment: i thought to reach elemans by id and create events by for loops. this is absolutely short-cut. thanks